# vimrc/vimperatorrc reusing and reassigning existing shortcut

Tags: vim, vimperator

Im using the firefox addon vimperator. The config file of vimperator (vimperatorrc), follows similar configuration like vim. I want to reassign an existing shortcut key to a new key, and use another key for the shortcut key that I reassigned. eg.

```
map x b
map b gT
```

1. Map x to b (buffers)
2. Map b to gT (previous tab)

After this, x also is mapped to b. I understand that it parse the complete file and decides the mappings.

However, is there a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `noremap x b` instead. (Think that's how it works.)